# jQuery AJAX program flow out of sequence

Tags: jquery

Building a prototype (concept) page that fakes out an approvals process.

When user clicks <kbd>#view_more</kbd> button, desired behavior is for the message "Requesting More Time" to appear in a div and continue to be visible while the javascript uses AJAX to call a PHP sleep function for ten seconds.

However, the message does not appear. Instead, the async ajax call results in the 10-second delay AND THEN the message appears for a split second before processing continues. How can I fix this?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on('click', '#view_more', function() {
    var cust = $('#cust').val();
    $('#buttons').html('<div id="countdown">Requesting More Time...</div>');
    $('#buttons').show();
    //Now, send email to admin
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
        data: 'request=more_viewing_time_requested_send_email&cust='+cust
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
        data: 'request=sleep_timer&delay=10'
    });
    alert('Additional viewing time authorized for this account.');
    location.reload(true);
});
```

PHP (ax_all_ajax_fns.php):

```
if ($_POST['request'] == 'sleep_timer') {
    $delay = (int)$_POST['delay'];
    sleep($delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always nice when one can eventually answer his own question.

The solution is to put the stuff you want to happen later inside success callback functions of the earlier things, so that:

1. Display the "Request In Progress" message
2. AJAX Call: more_viewing_time_req_send_email()
   2(a). in `send_email success function`: AJAX Call: sleep_timer() 10 seconds
           2(a)(i). in `sleep success function`: Display "Request Approved" message
           2(a)(ii). in `sleep success function`: Perform final desired action

Solution now looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#view_more', function() {
    var cust = $('#cust').val();
    $('#buttons').html('<div id="countdown">Requesting More Time...</div>');
    $('#buttons').show();
    //Now, send email to admin
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
        data: 'request=more_viewing_time_requested_send_email&cust='+cust,
        success: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
                data: 'request=sleep_timer&delay=10',
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Additional viewing time authorized.');
                        location.reload(true);
                    } //END success #2
            }); //END $.ajax #2
        } //END success #1
    }); //END AJAX more_viewing_time_send_email
}); //END $('view_more').click()
```

---

For those wondering (as I once was, not that long ago)... the reason I am using `$(document).on()` is because the <kbd>View More</kbd> button itself was earlier injected into its DIV by a previous AJAX call. Since the View More button didn't exist on the page when the page was first rendered, I must use `$(document).on()` in order to trap its click events. Had I used the more common `$('#view_more).click()` the code would not work because it could not see these events.